# Automate UFT Remote Agent Settings

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, alm

**Issue**: I need to change the UFT's Remote Agent Settings(image attached) **programmatically** on a machine before running my test set on that machine.

**Method(s) tried so far**:
I looked up on the internet and found that all the Remote Agent's Settings' values are placed inside the file `mic.ini` which is placed inside the bin folder in UFT's installation directory. I thought of opening the file as textstream using a filesystem object and make the required changes. But, it turns out, that I do not have admin rights on that bin folder due to which I am not able to save the changes made in mic.ini file(error: Access is Denied). Unfortunately, Getting the admin privileges is not an option for me.

Apart from this method, I could not find anything which would help me to accomplish this task.

Is there any other way I can change these settings programmatically? Is there an object model for the Remote Agent's Dialog which I can make use of?

[image: Remote Agent Settings]

Comment: Are you saying that from the GUI you are able to change the tick-box, instead the .ini file you cannot. Maybe something like selenium can help you in automate that and choose UFT "yes/no", but I am not sure that something like that exists! Have a nice day and good luck :-)

Comment: Yes. From GUI, I am able to change it but not from the mic.ini file

Comment: Strange, because you should be always the "same user". Anyway as said, maybe something like selenium can help you in automate this switch, but I am not sure. Unfortunately I have no exp in that :-)

Comment: Same here.I don't have any experience with Selenium.

Comment: Maybe somebody else have more exp. Or you can find something similar on internet, not sure, but wish you the best!

Comment: These are one time settings. Just curios, why you want to change it programmatically?

Comment: Actually, this is as per our client's request. They are not familiar with UFT or any of its settings. Only the execution results are relevant to them and hence need the minimal manual intervention. Even our test scripts are triggered automatically at a specific time and the reports are sent to them via email. Also, these test sets run on different host machines(on client's side). So, I just wanted to create a module that handles UFT remote agent settings before any test set is triggered on a machine.

Comment: Remote agent settings does not change automatically, you just need to set it one for the user under which you are going to run the tests. if you are using any scripts to control UFT, then those scripts can easily do  the tasks as per your requirements. I have the same setup and I use jenkins, it can send emails with the execution results and does not need any settings to be changed on the machine, if you can tell me what settings you want to change then I can probably help you in implementing it without changing Remote agent settings.

Comment: Suppose I want to uncheck the "Run GUI test sets in debug mode" and "keep UFT open after a test lab run session ends". How can I implement it?

Comment: How are you executing your UFT script? Using ALM/Jenkins/Batch file/VBS file?

Comment: @Manish The scripts are triggered from ALM. There is a scheduled vbs file which connects to ALM and then run the desired test set from ALM.

Comment: @ManishChristian Is there any way I can achieve this? Any possible way? Or any link which can help me?

Comment: @Kira, to be honest, I almost forgot abt this. Let me try to find something and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Can you post your .vbs file that you use? Also I am trying to understand why you want to leave UFT open after run session ends as ALM will launch UFT next time you run the script and this way you want hold the license unnecessarily.

Comment: @ManishChristian I want to uncheck that setting(uncheck keep uft open). So, I want the UFT to be closed after tests have run so that more machines can use the concurrent license. Also, I am sorry, I can't post the vbs file here(bound by client's conditions). But I can tell you what it does. It only connects to ALM using Open Test Architecture, finds the desired test set and triggers the execution on remote machines(It is on these machines where I want to change the UFT remote agent settings programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *This might NOT be the answer you are looking for, but this is what I found and justify itself.*

To start with option to uncheck `Keep UFT open...` option, here is the note directly from [**`UFT help file`**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Und_Remote_Agent_Settings_Dialog.htm):

> **Keep UFT open after a Test Lab run session ends:**
>
> By default, when ALM opens UFT on a remote computer during a test set
>   run (or when it runs selected tests or configurations from the Test
>   Lab module), it closes UFT at the end of that Test Lab run session.
>   This ensures that the UFT license is released at that point and made
>   available for other UFT users.
>
> Selecting this option causes UFT to stay open on your computer (and to
>   continue using the UFT license) after a Test Lab run session ends.
>
> Note: The behavior described above is relevant only when UFT is opened
>   from an ALM server that has the SUPPORT_TESTSET_END parameter set to
>   Y. (Y is the default setting). If UFT is opened from an earlier
>   version of ALM (or the above-mentioned parameter is set to N), this
>   option is ignored and UFT always remains open at the end of run
>   session.
>
> For details on the SUPPORT_TESTEND_END parameter, see the section on
>   setting ALM configuration parameters in the Application Lifecycle
>   Management Administrator Guide.

So as mentioned, ALM will close UFT by default if the `SUPPORT_TESTSET_END` parameter set to `Y`. So I would check with ALM admin team on this.

---

Now for option to uncheck `Run UFT in debug mode` option, you can keep UFT application object's RunMode option to `Fast`.

Note: You really don't need to do this change as ALM will run UFT scripts in Fast mode by default.

Here is the sample script for understanding:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim qtApp '~~> Declare the Application object variable

'~~> Create the UFT Application object
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") 

'~~> If UFT is notopen then open it
If qtApp.launched <> True then 
    qtApp.Launch 
End If 

'~~> Make the QUFT visible
qtApp.Visible = FALSE
If Not qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then
    '~~> Make changes in a test on Quality Center with version control
    qtApp.TDConnection.Connect "QC URL","DOMAIN Name","Project Name","User Name","Password",False
End If

'--------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim defaultRunMode, fastRunMode, normalRunMode
defaultRunMode = qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode

qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
fastRunMode = qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode

qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode = "Normal"
normalRunMode = qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode

Msgbox "Different RunModes" & VbCrLf & _
    VbTab & "DEFAULT RunMode : " & defaultRunMode & VbCrLf & _
    VbTab & "After FAST RunMode : " & fastRunMode & VbCrLf & _
    VbTab & "After NORMAL RunMode : " & normalRunMode
'--------------------------------------------------------------------

'~~> Script path  and script name in ALM
qtApp.Open "[ALM] Subject\QCScriptPath\ScriptName", False
qtApp.Test.Run
qtApp.TDConnection.Disconnect

'~~> Close UFT
qtApp.quit

'~~> Release Object
Set qtApp = Nothing

'~~> Handle Error
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Msgbox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End If
```

And here is the msgbox output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving these details(and the link). I didn't have idea about these default settings. But still I wanted to make these settings more configurable through script. Will keep on trying..

Comment: Glad to help... :)